# Symfony profiler doesnt work with multiple kernels

Tags: php, symfony, profiler

I made a new kernel on symfony application 3.3 using official docs http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/multiple_kernels.html

but I made a new folder api with all configs and added this if statement to app_dev and app in web folder

this is my app_dev.php file

```
    <?php

use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require_once(__DIR__.'/../c3.php');

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup
// for more information
//umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['127.0.0.1', '::1'], true) || PHP_SAPI === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
Debug::enable();

if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'api') !== false) {
    $kernel = new ApiKernel('dev', true);
} else {
    $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
}
if (PHP_VERSION_ID < 70000) {
    $kernel->loadClassCache();
}
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

This also works fine, but when I'm on api kernel symfony debug bar says that it cannot connect to profiler, also when I got response from api server and in header is

X-Debug-Token-Link →http://localhost:8000/_profiler/5cb1d5

But when I open this profiler is showing request only from app kernel nothing from api can you help me? Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're switching the kernel based on this condition :

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'api') !== false)
```

But when it comes to invoking the profiler route [http://localhost:8000/_profiler/5cb1d5] your REQUEST_URI doesn't fit the condition anymore and your are redirected to the other kernel (app in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Possible because if you want to enable profiler you Kernel should be in 'dev' environment. And debug should be run enabled.Try :

```
$kernel = new ApiKernel('dev', true);
```

Edited:(you should open new question instead of completly change question)
There are 2 posibility:

You don't have routes to your profiler. In this case add this to you routing.yml:

```
_profiler:
resource: "@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml"
prefix:   /_profiler
```

Or if you can't reach data in profiler maybe there are several changes in you kernel that are not catched. In this case you should follow this [instruction](https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler/data_collector.html) and add data_collector in your project

And the 3rd option - if you rewrite your Kernel than you forgot to add Profiler bundle, Try to add this to your registerBundles() method:

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();

        if ('dev' === $this->getEnvironment()) {
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle();
        }
    }
```

(taken form fresh sf Kernel)

Comment: I copied code from app.php in app_dev.php I have it like this, sorry for mistake I will change it

Comment: I have route to profiler, But maybe I need to use different profiler for api because profiler is called with app kernel, is there possibility to merge data from both?

Comment: I have found one more posiblity why you may have problem with profiler check updated answer